# What distros work with raspberry pi

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

Hi I was just wondering if literally any linux distro will work on raspberry pi for only Linux distro that are (for/made for) the raspberry pi

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ where their Help Center specifically states that Stack is for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Install [`rpi-imager`](https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-imager), at least in Ubuntu is avalilable as a `snap`.

When you run it you have the choices of several OS under *Other general-purpose OS*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think every linux distro, but there are many you can run. One for the pi specifically is called "rasbian" now renamed to "raspberry pi OS", based on Debian

I usually just use raspberry pi imager to format onto a sd card because it's quick and painless. You can also use it to install Ubuntu as well.

https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=using+raspberry+pi+imager